# XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>)) throws exception

Tags: .net-6.0, xmlserializer, excel-dna, mscorlib

I am using excel-dna to create an excel ribbon. I am saving the user settings using the xml serializer.

`XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Config>));`

this line of code was working in .net framework 4.7.2
migrated to .net 6 and it throws exception:
`"a non-collectible assembly may not reference a collectible assembly."`

when I debug, I see that it is not able to find
`system.private.corelib.xmlserializers.dll`
in
`C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.16`

I tried assign extra attibutes in the custom type Config.
I tried to passing in additional parameters in the serializer, such as additional type Config and xmlroot attribute.
It has made no difference.

Comment: fixed it using this instead: 
DataContractSerializer formatter = new DataContractSerializer(content.GetType());
formatter.WriteObject(outFile, content);

Comment: this is the main solution:
https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/450